# Breadth First Search of Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to make a breadth first search function for a binary search tree, but I don't seem to be able to make it work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::displayBfs(T searchKey, BST<T> *node)
{
    BST<T> *tmp = node;
    queue <int> queue;
    queue.push(node->mData);

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return false;    
    }

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        queue.pop();
        if (tmp->mData == searchKey)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if(tmp->mLeft != NULL)
                queue.push(tmp->mLeft->mData);
            if(tmp->mRight != NULL)
                queue.push(tmp->mRight->mData);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Any symptoms? Is it compilation or runtime error?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot I removed that line by accident. tmp is defined now.

It's a runtime error. It just gets stuck in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `BST<T>` nodes have the information about their children, you have to put them on the queue, not the values as you are doing. Other thing is that you ain't getting the element from the `queue` before popping it. And finally you have to give other name to your queue because of the `std::queue` I'm assuming you are using.

Try to rewrite your BFS this way:

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::displayBfs(T searchKey, BST<T> *node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return false;

    queue<BST<T>*> q;
    q.push(node);

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        BST<T>* tmp = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (tmp->mData == searchKey)
            return true;
        else
        {
            if(tmp->mLeft != NULL)
                q.push(tmp->mLeft);
            if(tmp->mRight != NULL)
                q.push(tmp->mRight);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I will. I have to wait a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

The test for `node == NULL` should come before you access the node:

```
if (node == NULL)
    return false;    
queue.push(node);
```

Also your queue should be of node type and you should be inserting the nodes in the queue:

queue*> queue;

And finally you are not not accessing the dequed element, you need to use the `front` method of the queue class to access the front element before you call pop.